# How can I get and display imap emails with attachments and display

Tags: php, email, imap, email-attachments

I'm trying to grab an email and display the body of the email as well as links to download any attachments. I've had success with other emails without attachments but with this, I can't even find the body.

My questions:

1. Where is the body? How do I get it in readable format?
2. If I were to link to an attachment, what kind of code would I have to use to display the attachment?

Thanks in advance!

--

expected email body:

```
This s the second test with attachments
```

expected email attachment:

[image: attachment.png]

code:

```
$mbox = imap_open($mailbox_path, $username, $password);

$msgs = imap_sort($mbox, SORTDATE, 1, SE_UID);

$msguid = array_shift($msgs);

$email['msgno'] = imap_msgno($mbox, $msguid);
$email['body'] = imap_fetchbody($mbox, $email['msgno'], 2);
$email['printable_body'] = quoted_printable_decode($email['body']);
$email['attachments'] = getAttachments($mbox, $email['msgno']);

print_r($email);

function getAttachments($connection, $message_number) {
    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($connection, $message_number);
    $attachments = array();
    if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) {
            $attachments[$i] = array(
                'is_attachment' => false,
                'filename' => '',
                'name' => '',
                'attachment' => ''
            );

            if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) {
                foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) {
                    if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') {
                        $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                        $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                    }
                }
            }

            if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) {
                foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
                    if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                        $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                        $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                    }
                }
            }

            if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) {
                $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($connection, $message_number, $i+1);
                if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) { // 3 = BASE64
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                }
                elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) { // 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $attachments;
}
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [msgno] => 1
    [body] =>     bWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAA09JREFUeNqUVG1MTmEYfr7PKzYjZvODZlr+hFlo813GD5+LTKtNs6aX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    [printable_body] => iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJ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    [attachments] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [is_attachment] => 
                    [filename] => 
                    [name] => 
                    [attachment] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [is_attachment] => 1
                    [filename] => attachment.png
                    [name] => attachment.png
                    [attachment] => ‰PNG    

IHDR‰
tEXtSoftwareAdobe ImageReadyqÉe<OIDATxÚ”TmLNa~¾Ï+6#fóƒfZþ„Yhó]ÆŸ‹L«M³¦—F~(?Ø²RÃF^Äë"¤šÏ™š‘úÇ0ËÌ…™z;Ïq-ôg»Ï}žû¹ïë¹îçPòÏ´eéÂ²Ìx«Û\aÛf,L”ùX¾r¥Œ×5„ý+ØÌUYÁ1B¿PŠJå; Ã°-åxy~¢?¹é~N\â1y£µN©\Ë(„l8¼kÚòfŸ@4ƒR:~­ý2„ÓdH6d4ç|!HÄ0Î+=0o¿©æ$‘RuI)1Ã™›$XÍs]÷9–íMÆw•KÜö^>>Ã¼³±×&ÑØâu[¸£uœ2ò>ÊèJWkóZp`‰?ŸÀî¥÷Åqœ‘Xd».yt-XzÚ‹eRFŠs ÍBŠaŒ±Hõìt0ÔjÈ8ìÇÃÇ9»ÿ+¶O@tlœ§ ,uœ?¤îÊÑ½m+6n§°Ï‡L€HØS¡kã/~ÅþUÃU›8ê’Š´jÀ45áûJ˜££8åIÌeU^Ã`oÕšV]8RB"2DÐlœÚÉo„NÄ˜Ü@Ê¯Ò¶*¬'A4ÊÐ    ½öŠe%ßzÇÿ˜¹mwœR*²Çgø&B;úê@QHI5ÕPÆe¨ZØr¤’÷Î
ŸüI¨'å
E¤i™i8õ£ÔDç‘RSpg^gNñAÒÝm&£Ÿ°¯ %BnõUÑ«“%ãR† h¯‹ø.ïq¶$Ž÷j—À3æ>'Ä{å—%æ.N/µv.¢k£aÞŠú=`Œ¾Å¼e`¿Œ3…Cf8Ú)l]ÿ9"C)ÅP¡Ý¡p~jÚÖWœÓ–'0_é˜»°ºi0öÎ«ŒvõUË¢‘nXpÏ7Ú»bÛ²R]hï®ÖÿRzê2û
•hGw€ií®Ü47`¸Ë†R¦ÏPbÏˆ:\}ýïS…ŸXÃPÇwøÓœþ~(â'àG!ø{ÁEêÔÓÏ^y½ óLËÚŒå1Û±ôßìù9”_º=VIY€F8Rˆ£¸ÐíhÆt4`¥mÛwBÝf ;e¾5`ÏØ€]Àö    ÜU°Í£” ´X¤‚p÷î¿€yÏw·N»÷·ÂØIEND®B`‚
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: You're hardcoding the location of the body. You need to fetch the structure of the message and scan it to find the body, since it is not in a fixed location of the overall message.

Comment: No. I just forgot to include that function. I'm editing that now.